# why recvfrom() still block when a SIGALRM has been captured?

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, network-programming

I want to use `alarm()` to set the timeout of `recvfrom`. But found that when use `signal()` to register a handler for `SIGALRM`, and a `SIGALRM` has been captured and then invoked the signal handler. But after returned from handler, the `recvfrom()` still blocks while there is no data coming and there is no `EINTR` error. Why? Does the `signal()` set the `SA_RESTART` flag automatically?
Here is the code:

```
signal(SIGALRM, sig_handler);
while(1)
{
    alarm(5);
    n = recvfrom(sock, buf, BUF_MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
    if(n < 0)
    {
        if(errno == EINTR)
        {
            printf("recvfrom timeout\n");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recvfrom error\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         printf("data: %s\n", buf);
         alarm(0);
    }
}

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: The real question is why aren't you using SO_RCVTIMEO?

Answer (score 1):

Whether the blocking call is restarted is a platform dependent attribute, according to `signal`'s man page:

> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
> - By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD
>          semantics.   This  default  behavior  is  provided as long as a suitable feature test macro is defined: _BSD_SOURCE on glibc 2.19 and earlier or _DEFAULT_SOURCE in
>          glibc 2.19 and later.  (By default, these macros are defined; see feature_test_macros(7) for details.)  If such a feature test macro is not defined, then  signal()
>          provides System V semantics.

Since BSD semantics are equivalent to calling `sigaction(2)` with the following flags:

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

and System V semantics does not do `SA_RESTART`, what you saw is that your program is doing the BSD way, so you should make sure use the said feature test macros to get defined bahavior of your program.